# .net Core 3 upload file not working, Request.Form.Files is empty

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have researched many articles and tried many things. This was all working when the site was using .net Core 2. I needed to upgrade my .net core site from 2 to 3.2 so I started a new projected and migrated angular to the new site.
I am using a third party library to upload a scanned pdf or tiff Dynamic Web TWAIN.
Now the Request.Form.Files is empty.

```
    [HttpPost("UploadFiles/{fileName}"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(String fileName)
    {
        IFormFileCollection files = Request.Form.Files; //This is empty

    }
```

I have tried adding paramters to the UploadFiles method, but all of them are null

```
IFormFile RemoteFile
List<IFormFile> RemoteFile
[FromForm(Name = "RemoteFile")] IFormFile RemoteFile
```

From the Form Data I can get the file in a string, but I cant figure out how to convert that string to a valid pdf or tiff

```
IFormCollection form = Request.Form;
string stringData = form["RemoteFile"];
```

Posted request headers and form data.

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried the method [GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfilecollection.getfiles?view=aspnetcore-3.1)?

Comment: Shouldn't the file be accessible via [Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformcollection.files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormCollection_Files)?

Comment: @yushulx are you talking about Request.Form.GetFiles(), that method does not exists

Comment: Tom, Files is empty, in .net core 2 it was working but in 3 it is not

Comment: Does anyone have any idea, I am still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this sample: https://github.com/Dynamsoft/web-twain-ASP.NET-Core

The code for uploading image files is as follows:

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FileController : ControllerBase
    {
        // POST api/<FileController>
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
        {
            var files = Request.Form.Files;
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace.ToString());
                    return Unauthorized("not able to create");
                }
            }
            foreach (var uploadFile in files)
            {
                var fileName = uploadFile.FileName;
                using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(path, fileName)))
                {
                    await uploadFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```